# Periodical status messages by Jopr?

Tags: email, jboss, monitoring, redhat

I'm evaluating Jopr 2.3.1 to monitor a JBoss 4.2.3 Application Server.
Jopr, based on the better known RHQ Project from Redhat, supports to send email notifications triggered by so called alerts. Alerts can be defined to react to certain changes of system parameter such as metrics (e.g. 'Active Thread Count', 'JVM Free Memory') or the availability (e.g. goes UP, goes DOWN) changes.

I'm now wondering if it's also possible to send a for instance weekly status report by email?
Just to make sure: This email notification is to be send periodically, indipendent of the regular alter notification, rather problems occured or not.

Many thanks in advance - every hint is appreciated
Tobias

Answer (score 0):

RHQ 3 (anything Jopr related is old and outdated) has server side plugins.
They can be alert notification senders that let you e.g. connect to a trouble ticket system for alert notifications.
They can also be more generic and can be triggered periodically via an "internal cron". The latter may be what you want for report sending. In fact, Mazz has already written an example plugin generating a report on file system - you would only need to change the "write to disk" to "send email".

http://rhq-project.org/